# Python os.system cannot find path when it exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, path

I would like to launch `WindowsSandbox.exe` with python which is under `C:\Windows\System32\`. But for some reason, it just didn't work, despite another executable (`cmd.exe`) is in the exact same location.

No idea why this happened (Environment: `Windows 10 1909 Python 3.8.0`):

CMD:

```
C:\>where calc.exe
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

C:\>where WindowsSandbox.exe
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsSandbox.exe
```

Python:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("calc.exe") # Opens calculator without any problem
0
>>> os.system("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe") # Opens calculator without any problem
0
>>> os.system("WindowsSandbox.exe")
'WindowsSandbox.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
>>> os.system("C:/Windows/System32/WindowsSandbox.exe")
'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsSandbox.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
>>>
```

Nodejs (Just for proofing it should work on python):

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.13.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const { execSync } = require("child_process")
undefined
> execSync('calc.exe') //Able to launch calculator
<Buffer >
> execSync('C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe') //Able to launch calculator
<Buffer >
> execSync('WindowsSandbox.exe') //Able to launch Windows Sandbox
<Buffer >
> execSync('C:/Windows/System32/WindowsSandbox.exe') //Able to launch Windows Sandbox
<Buffer >
>
```

I also tried double escape (`'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsSandbox.exe'`), raw string (`r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsSandbox.exe'`) and backward slash (`'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsSandbox.exe'`). They all doesn't work

The `%PATH%` should have no problem (as `cmd.exe` and `WindowsSandbox.exe` can be both run directly from cmd).

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The reason is quite simple: There are two `C:\Windows\System32` on 64-bit Windows. The first one is `%SystemRoot%\System32` containing the 64-bit executables. The second one is `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` containing the 32-bit executables. Whenever a 32-bit application wants to access the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`, the [Windows File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) redirects this file system access to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` as documented by Microsoft.

Comment: So on using 32-bit `python.exe` the usage of `os.system` results in usage of environment variable `ComSpec` which is defined with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` which results in execution of 32-bit `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` on your computer which searches now for `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsSandbox.exe` redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsSandbox.exe` and this executable file does not exist in that directory. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Is there any way to call `WindowsSandbox.exe` or any other 64bit programs from "actual" `C:/Windows/System32` with 32-bit Python?

Override the %ComSpec% variable?

Comment: It would be a good idea to check in Python script file in which environment it is executed, i.e. if being executed by 32-bit or 64-bit Python on 64-bit Windows. This can be very easily done by getting the value of environment variable `SystemRoot`, concatenating its string value with `\Sysnative\cmd.exe` and checking if this file exists. That is true only on 64-bit Windows with Python script executed in 32-bit environment. In this case the full qualified file name of `WindowsSandbox.exe` is the string value of environment variable `SystemRoot` concatenated with `\Sysnative\WindowsSandbox.exe`.

Comment: On 32-bit Windows and on execution of the Python script by 64-bit Python on 64-bit Windows the file `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` does not exist and so the correct full qualified file name of `WindowsSandbox.exe` is the string value of environment variable `SystemRoot` concatenated with `\System32\WindowsSandbox.exe`. However, the usage of `os.system` is deprecated and should not be used anymore. The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) should be used nowadays on writing new Python code using Python 3.x.x.

Comment: It is definitely a 64bit system with 32bit Python (`os.path.isfile(os.getenv("SystemRoot") + "\Sysnative\cmd.exe")` returns `True`) and indeed changed to `WindowsSandbox.exe` works. Thanks a lot for the explainations!

Answer (score 0):

The `os.path` module has methods to fix directory path information, verify existence of targets, etc.